# Java - How to fetch email address from phpMyAdmin and send using javamail

Tags: java, mysql, email, phpmyadmin, jakarta-mail

I've designed **ForgotMyPassword.java** jFrame Form on NetBeans IDE 8.2
wherein I'm using phpMyAdmin for fetching the E-Mail Address of registered users from it and sending it to their E-Mail Addresses through MYSQL Database using JavaMail

I basically want to fetch the E-Mail Address of registered users from it and send it to their E-Mail Addresses through MYSQL Database using JavaMail as One Time Password (OTP) recovery option

Here's the source code :

```
    String username = usrnmfield.getText();
    String email = emailID.getText();
    String[] to = {"emailaddr@gmail.com"};

    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement pstn = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/app" , "xxxx" , "xxxx");
        pstn=db.prepareStatement("select * from register where USERNAME=? and EMAIL=?");

        pstn.setString(1,username);
        pstn.setString(2,email);

        ResultSet i=pstn.executeQuery();

        if(i.next())

        {


    if(JavaMail.send
    ("abc@gmail.com", 
    "xxxx",
    to,
    "Hello world",
    "Thank you for reading my post"))

    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , " Please Check out your Inbox for any Password sent by us to you ");

        }

        }

        else if (usrnmfield != i && emailID != i)

        {

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username or E-Mail ID");

        }     

    } catch(HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }


}
```

Comment: Please state the problem

Comment: yes , i mean how do i fetch each and every registered user i.e. (the one whose account is registered with my Java Application and in my MySQL Database (PhpMyAdmin) ) of email addresses from MySQL Database (PhpMyAdmin) using Java JDBC and send each of them the particular encrypted passwords to their email accounts for the recovery process using JavaMail only and once they have received the encrypted passwords , it can help in recovery of their forgotten passwords so that the forgotten password can be recovered easily

eg : https://s1.postimg.org/8d0r91udqn/screenshot_120.png

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks and adjustments that could help:

0. Concerning your application design you should strongly consider another architecture. It is far not recommended to let a client (desktop) app work directly with the SQL database for security matters. Implementing the whole security on the client-side is obviously a bad idea (and will get bypassed easily) as well as it will be unmanageable. Consider using a centralized secure database on a distant also secure server that provides state-of-the-art authentication and authorization mecanisms (eg. through REST-API over HTTPS). Server-side security frameworks include Keycloak, SpringSecurity, Apache Shiro, JaaS... By searching the Web you will see that your design is not so common. Moreover for OTP the use of a Web server or simply remote exchanges seem obvious (and you will need them). You may also consider implement logging through a centralized LDAP server.
1. Name your fields in the select statement. Eg. `"select password from register where ..."` so that you know what you expect in order OR use the field name when using `select *`:

   `ResultSet rs = ... String myValue = rs.getString(1); String myValueBis = rs.getString("password");`
2. Always surround your database queries with a try-finally block in order to close your ResultSet, the prepared statement and eventually the connection (if not reused) and preferably in this order.
3. I don't see the purpose of this condition:

   `else if (usrnmfield != i && emailID != i) { ...`

   You are comparing text fields against a ResultSet but neither the value contained in the text nor the values of the current row of the ResultSet (cf. 1). This makes no sense.
4. If you want to allow you user to retrieve its password based on its username or its e-mail you should consider using an "OR" (instead of "and") in your SQL statement.
5. When using JavaMail you must make sure that your Session contains enough information to send an email. It is generally the first step in any JavaMail app to create a `javax.mail.Session` object. So you need to configure the smtp server or relay, eventually the port and authentication. As you don't show the code of your JavaMail class I suggest you put it in your original question if you have any issue about it and clarify what is the problem (if any).
6. Generally speaking if you consider using this app for commercial use or some serious purpose you should also quickly think about storing your passwords in an encrypted way (eg. as SHA-256). And also think about not sending the password via E-mail (it will out come naturally if you only store the hash of the users' password...) but instead propose them a secure way to reset/renew it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i will surely make sure of the following mentioned points but i want to fetch the E-Mail Addresses of registered users from my PhpMyAdmin and send it to their email addresses through MYSQL Database using JavaMail as One Time Password (OTP) recovery option" right now

Comment: I feel sorry but actually I don't get it. Your question seems not clear to me. What do you mean by "fetch the E-Mail Addresses of registered users from my PhpMyAdmin"? PhpMyAdmin is just a Web UI over MySQL so your users are present in the MySQL db. So I guess you mean "fetch from MySQL db"? Secondly what is your exact problem? Do you want indications on how to achieve al of this or do you have (very) particular issues in implementing the mails fetching part or OTP or...?

Comment: yes , i mean how do i fetch each and every registered user i.e. (the one whose account is registered with my Java Application and in my MySQL Database (PhpMyAdmin) ) of email addresses from MySQL Database (PhpMyAdmin) using Java JDBC and send each of them the particular encrypted passwords to their email accounts for the recovery process using JavaMail only and once they have received the encrypted passwords , it can help in recovery of their forgotten passwords so that the forgotten password can be recovered easily

eg : https://s1.postimg.org/8d0r91udqn/screenshot_120.png

Comment: Hum still a bit wide as a question. But to start with something, try `select EMAIL from register` then iterate on the ResultSet where `getString("EMAIL")" will give you each user e-mail address. Then generate a random password per user and send it as a link and/or update your database with OTP password that they need to enter next time they come in (or implicitely through the use of the link - containing this password). And then: the rest...

Comment: By the way (and it's important): I strongly suggest that you revise your design as implementing security in that way on the (desktop) client side will quickly make you run into a wall. In other words you should have a client-server architecture (if you want decent security) with a security framework running on the server (bound to its local DB eventually) and only a (Web) authenticator in the desktop app. It is strange nowadays to have a Swing app directly accessing a MySQL database for authentication! (and how if it is not centralized and secure?).

Comment: Last but not least: try have a look to **Apache Shiro** if you still want to implement authentication in your desktop application. Or if you plan to run your desktop clients in a managed environment, why not go for **LDAP** ?

Comment: i'm right now facing the actual problem at line no. 5 where String[] to = {"email address"}; which is supposed to be String[] to = {"emailID.gettext();"}; so that it could send to the particular email address of the registered user

please have a look at this link : https://s1.postimg.org/86yafjz5f3/screenshot_124.png

It omits this error "incompatible types string cannot be converted to string"  whenever i type String[] to = emailID.getText();

While the email address is supposed to be of String Type

Thank you

Comment: `String[] to = emailID.getText()`can't work. You are assigning a String to an array of String..

Comment: i'm really sorry but i'm new to it , May you please help me with the source code of it just for time saving purpose

Actually i want to submit the application project in a week to my faculty

Thank you

Comment: I'd be glad to help but you don't help us. This discussion is clearly not constructive and [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (if at least there is a topic?). For your very last question, maybe `String[] to = { emailID.getText() };` For the rest please read the chart of StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [how to formulate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks